# find max consecutive sum, find segments containing a point

Tags: algorithm

1) Given an array of integers (negative and positive) - what is the most efficient algorithm to return the max consecutive sum.

a) I thought to solve this with Dynamic Programing, but complexity is O(n^2). Is there another way?

b) What if we were given a infinite input of integers. Is there a way to output the current max consecutive sum? I guess not.

2) Given: an array of segments[start,end] (can elapse) ordered ascending by start point, 
and a point.

What is the most efficient algorithm to return a segment that contains this point?/all segments that contain this point?
I thought to use binarySearch to hit the first segment that starts before this point the than trying to traverse right and left.

Any other idea ?

Comment: Please don't post multiple questions inside a single SO question - make this two separate questions. Incidentally for the answer to (1) I suggest you read Programming Pearls by Bentley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) There is an [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane.27s_algorithm) that's working in O(n)

For 2) I think your approach is not bad (as long as you can't assume ordering w.r.t. ending points)

Answer (score 1):

1) As long as the sum doesn't drop below zero, it's always better to continue with the consecutive summation. So you just pass through the array once (i.e. you have a linear runtime algorithm) from left to right and remember the current consecutive summation and the maximum consecutive summation so far, updating it whenever the current sum gets bigger then the max sum.

So at any point at of the array traversal, you can say what the max sum so far is. Hence you can use this algorithm for an (infinite) input stream, too.

2) Yes, binary search sounds good. But if I understand the question correctly, you can start with the right-most segment (that starts closest to the point) and then just traverse the segments to the left. Of course, the worst case runtime is still linear in the number of segments, but the average should be logarithmic.

Comment: the right-most segment (that starts closest to the point) - you find that by BinarySearch? I don't see how you change my binarySearch idea? ("But if..." means there is a change. no?)

Comment: @Elad: added comment to explicitly cover 1)b). For your second comment: you said "trying to traverse right and left." but since your end points are unordered and within the segments, you only need to traverse to the left.